# ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT error when using stdout for node.js / express

Tags: node.js, express, stdout

Running into the well documented "Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client" in my node app. I have reviewed existing pages dedicated to this issue and tried their remedies - mainly making sure to "return" all other responses; however the error still persists. Code below.

You'll notice I have a bunch of different paths calling unique python functions via subprocess. Interestingly the http error only shows up for certain paths - typically those with very large output. In all cases the response arrives and renders on the client side just fine, but with the larger responses I get the http error and my app shuts down. I can think of a few potential non-middleware causes for this - Potentially res.send() behaves differently as the responses get large? Or perhaps it's subprocess.stdout causing issues with the larger responses? Alternatively the longer response time could be causing the browser to resend the request before the response is delivered?... Would like to rule these out before going deeper into potential middleware issues. Thanks

```
router.get('/element/chart', ensureAuthenticated, (req,res) => {
    const path = require('path')
    const {spawn} = require('child_process')
    console.log(current_data_page_id)
    console.log(typeof current_data_page_id)
    let runScript;

    runScript = (current_data_page_id) => {
        switch(current_data_page_id) {
            case "100":
                return spawn('python', ["-u", path.join(process.cwd(),'/python/python_func_1.py')]); 
            break;
            case "101":
                return spawn('python', ["-u", path.join(process.cwd(),'/python/python_func_2.py')]);
            break;
            case "102":
                return spawn('python', ["-u", path.join(process.cwd(),'/python/python_func_3.py')]);
            break;
            case "103":
                return spawn('python', ["-u", path.join(process.cwd(),'/python/python_func_4.py')]);
            break;
            case "104":
                return spawn('python', ["-u", path.join(process.cwd(),'/python/python_func_5.py')]);
            break;
            case "200":
                return spawn('python', ["-u", path.join(process.cwd(),'/python/python_func_6.py')]);
            break;
            case "201": 
                return spawn('python', ["-u", path.join(process.cwd(),'/python/python_func_7.py')]);
            break;
            case "202": 
                return spawn('python', ["-u", path.join(process.cwd(),'/python/python_func_8.py')]);
            break;
            default:
                console.log("Data page ID does not match current options") 
        };
    };
    
    const subprocess = runScript(current_data_page_id)
    // print output of script
    subprocess.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
        var dataToSend = data.toString();
        console.log(dataToSend);
        res.send(dataToSend);
        res.end('end')
        return;
    });
    subprocess.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
        console.log(`error:${data}`);
        return;
    });
    subprocess.stderr.on('close', () => {
        console.log("Closed");
        return;
    });

});

// ensureAuthenticated middleware
module.exports = {
    ensureAuthenticated: function(req, res, next) {  
        if(req.isAuthenticated()) {
            return next();
        }
        req.flash('error_msg', 'Please log in to view this resource');
        res.sendFile(process.cwd() + '/views/login.html');
        return;
    }
}
```

Console output below. Stack trace points to the "res.send(dataToSend);" line.

```
_http_outgoing.js:536
    throw new ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT('set');
    ^

Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
```

Comment: You are calling `res.end('end')` in your `data` event listener, there for the connection to the client get closed and a new `res.send(...)` dosn't work. Also it is bad practise to declare the "runScript" function in every request...

Comment: @Marc thanks for the comment; I removed `res.end('end')` and still get the error.

Comment: Where is `current_data_page_id` & `ensureAuthenticated` defined ?! and more important what is the source code of the "ensureAuthenticated" middleware ? Perhaps the middleware allready send stuff to the client

Comment: ensureAuthenticated is defined in separate js file; updated the post to include the code; current_data_page_id is a global variable which is assigned via a different request, and is flowing through just fine atm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason of the error is you call "end" request to many time, a http request just need finish only once time.
You call `res.send(dataToSend);` or `res.end('end')` this mean you finish the request 2 times.

When you remove `res.end('end');` line, the error still appear, because `res.send(dataToSend);` has been called more than once time, because I think your "python" command more than 1 line of data, then `subprocess.stdout.on('data'` has been call many time.

The idea for that case is just end the request when the "command" finish (done), you can catch "done" event with `close` event of `spawn` process (not `subprocess.stdout`).

With the data (output of the command) we have 2 ways:

- Append output to a string variable and send it to client when the command done

```
var data = ''; // init data store
subprocess.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
  var dataToSend = data.toString();
  console.log(dataToSend);
  data += dataToSend + '\n'; // append data with new line char :)
  // res.send(dataToSend);
  // res.end('end')
  // return;
});

// subscribe to close event
subprocess.on('close', (code) => {
  if (code !== 0) {
    console.log(`grep process exited with code ${code}`);
  }
  res.send(data); // send data to client and finish the request
});
```

- Use express api to write response to `res` object (I like this way)

```
subprocess.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
  var dataToSend = data.toString();
  console.log(dataToSend);
  res.write(dataToSend); // write data to response stream
  // res.send(dataToSend);
  // res.end('end')
  // return;
});

// subscribe to close event
subprocess.on('close', (code) => {
  if (code !== 0) {
    console.log(`grep process exited with code ${code}`);
  }
  res.end(); // finish the request, `end` not `send`
});
```

Comment: thank you! that solved the problem! (I ended up using the second approach)